# Are All Spark Filepaths basically Paths in the Driver Node?

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

Learning Spark version 3.4.0 using Scala version 2.12.17 on a laptop running Ubuntu 22.04.

From some online documentations and tutorials, I have understood this is how the general spark architecture looks like.

[image: Scala Architecture]

Although right now everything is on my localhost, in general, every box above can be running on a different EC2 instance, am I correct?

However, in that case, do all the filepaths in my `.scala` code represent paths in the driver? As an example, if I run this on a spark RDD frame (when the cluster has many executors on different nodes),

```
df.write.parquet("/root/della/Downloads/output/tensorflow_clusters.parquet")
```

then will the entire frame go to the said directory locally in the driver, so that even if the workers and the manager die eventually, the driver has full access to the data locally? This is a concept I have not seen clarified explicitly in the tutorials.

Also, related, suppose, I want to put the parquet in some mountable cloud storage like AWS S3 bucket. May I, in that case, mount the bucket at a convenient directory *only in the driver* (e.g. using [s3fs](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse)), and then seamlessly write to the bucket (via the local directory in the driver)? Or do I need to mount the bucket on every executor?

I have used the bucket mount technique in python pandas (of course, running on a single machine) previously for I/O from cloud, wondering if it happens the same way in spark.

Comment: It depends how you configure the application. `/tmp/foo` can point to the Driver's local disk, but also to `hdfs://nn1:8020/tmp/foo/`.

Comment: @shay__ thanks for getting back. Can you point to any documentation on which specific configuration controls this? Is it part of the spark cluster set up or a specific spark job etc.?

Comment: Spark actions like write are executed in the executors, so yes, executors must be able to access to the hdfs path. If one of themcrashes, the stage fails and although neither HDFS nor S3 provide any rollback mechanism. In my experience with HDFS, the file can be corrupted or with  a folder with a temporary file... but Spark notifies the crash.

Comment: @EmilianoMartinez thanks, I am not specifically asking about HDFS. I am merely asking how spark interprets the line of code when I ask it to write, with a file path. Does it go look for that path in HDFS, or driver file system, or is that configured by some other setting on where spark goes to look for that path? Is there any documentation around it?

Comment: @EmilianoMartinez or, does that line of code itself point out the correct place to look for that path? Where can I find documentations of these parameters/path patterns etc.?

Comment: See stevel's answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a "default filesystem" for which paths that aren't fully qualified URLs are resolved against. This is set in the hadoop option `fs.defaultFS`, default of local filesystem, so is effectively

```
spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS file:///
```

*unless you change this*, a path like `"/root/della/Downloads/output/tensorflow_clusters.parquet"`

will be resolved on each host differently. They won't see each others work unless you mount a shared filesystem, e.g. nfs.

The hadoop filesystem APIs, which spark uses, were written to work with distributed filesystems without you needing to mount them locally. You need

1. a distributed filesystem.
2. Your workers having access permission
3. URLs which reference it, or that default fs option set to say "this is the default"

Note, s3 is almost but not quite a distributed filesystem, for reasons which are well documented elsewhere. It is possible to use it as the cluster FS for spark, but you need a special "committer" to safely right work: S3A committers, EMR Spark Committer, *or use an S3-first table format such as Iceberg, Delta or Hudi"